# In aws cloudformation, it giving error when I try to use !sub and !join function together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I am trying following in cfn template :

```
ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref kinesiss3logpolicy
      PermissionsBoundary: !Sub 
          - !Join [ '',[ 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/', !Ref AdminPolicy ] ]
```

where AdminPolicy is a parameter.

I get following error :

```
*[error]ValidationError: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string*
```

can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: YAML policy indentation is odd.

Comment: Couldn't you just use !Sub without !Join (see last example [here](https://theburningmonk.com/2019/05/cloudformation-protip-use-fnsub-instead-of-fnjoin/))?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of using Sub according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html).

You must provide a value map to `Sub`, unless you're only using directly substitutable parameters.

You have defined parameters for `!Sub` as a list because you're using `-`.

```
PermissionsBoundary: !Sub 
    - !Join [ '',[ 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/', !Ref AdminPolicy ] ]
```

**This doesn't work**. If you're using a list for `Sub`, then you must provide a value map.

Then you should use `!Sub` in a single line because you're only using pseudo parameters and your own parameters.

Then you have to use it like this, but this has a syntax error. But the idea is the same.

```
PermissionsBoundary: !Sub !Join [ '',[ 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/', !Ref AdminPolicy ] ]
```

Then you can use the `Fn` notation, instead of the shorthand notation.

```
PermissionsBoundary: { Fn::Sub: {Fn::Join: [ '',[ 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/', !Ref AdminPolicy ] ] } }
```

As it's mentioned in the comments, you can remove `!Join` and only use `!Sub`.

```
PermissionsBoundary: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/${AdminPolicy}"
```